# The mysterious case of the unexpected implicit interface variable

Tags: delphi, interface

I recently came across some behaviour that I simply could not and cannot explain, related to Delphi interface variables.

Essentially, it boils down to an implicit interface variable that the compiler generates in the `Broadcast` method.

At the end statement that terminates the method, the epilogue code contains two calls to `IntfClear`.  One of which I can explain, it corresponds to the `Listener` local variable. The other one I cannot explain and it takes you to `TComponent._Release` (Debug DCUs) after the object instance has been destroyed. It doesn't result in an AV, but that's just lucky, and with full FastMM debug a post-destruction instance access is reported.

Here's the code:

```
program UnexpectedImplicitInterfaceVariable;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

type
  IListener = interface
    ['{6D905909-98F6-442A-974F-9BF5D381108E}']
    procedure HandleMessage(Msg: Integer);
  end;

  TListener = class(TComponent, IListener)
  //TComponent._AddRef and TComponent_Release return -1
  private
    procedure HandleMessage(Msg: Integer);
  end;

{ TListener }

procedure TListener.HandleMessage(Msg: Integer);
begin
end;

type
  TBroadcaster = class
  private
    FListeners: IInterfaceList;
    FListener: TListener;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure Broadcast(Msg: Integer);
  end;

constructor TBroadcaster.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FListeners := TInterfaceList.Create;
  FListener := TListener.Create(nil);
  FListeners.Add(FListener);
end;

procedure TBroadcaster.Broadcast(Msg: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
  Listener: IListener;
begin
  for i := 0 to FListeners.Count-1 do
  begin
    Listener := FListeners[i] as IListener;
    Listener.HandleMessage(Msg);
  end;
  Listener := nil;

  FListeners.Clear;
  FreeAndNil(FListener);
end;//method epilogue: why is there a call to IntfClear and then TComponent._Release?

begin
  with TBroadcaster.Create do
  begin
    Broadcast(42);
    Free;
  end;
end.
```

And here's the disassembly of the epilogue:

[image]

There, clear as day, are the two calls to IntfClear.

So, who can see the obvious explanation that I am missing?

---

**UPDATE**

Well, Uwe got it straight away. `FListeners[i]` needs a temporary implicit variable for its result variable. I didn't see that since I was assigning to `Listener`, but of course that's a different variable.

The following variant is an explicit representation of what the compiler is generating for my original code.

```
procedure TBroadcaster.Broadcast(Msg: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
  Intf: IInterface;
  Listener: IListener;
begin
  for i := 0 to FListeners.Count-1 do
  begin
    Intf := FListeners[i];
    Listener := Intf as IListener;
    Listener.HandleMessage(Msg);
  end;
  Listener := nil;

  FListeners.Clear;
  FreeAndNil(FListener);
end;
```

When written this way it is obvious that Intf cannot be cleared until the epilogue.

Comment: BTW: This is one reason why, when mixing object and interface reference paradigms I'd prefer to inherit from `TInterfacedObject` and manually reference count my object references as needed. `(FListener as IUnknown)._AddRef` and instead of typical object style destruction... `(FListener as IUnknown)._Release` (which probably in most cases results in immediate self-destruction).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just a guess, but perhaps the `FListeners[i] as IListener` uses a temporary variable for `FListeners[i]`. After all it is the result of a function call.

Comment: Yes, that's it - see updated question for corresponding code. Thanks, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 11):

Uwe Raabe is correct, if you look at the code further up:

```
Project4.dpr.51: Listener := FListeners[i] as IListener;
00441C16 8D4DE0           lea ecx,[ebp-$20]
00441C19 8B55F4           mov edx,[ebp-$0c]
00441C1C 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
00441C1F 8B4004           mov eax,[eax+$04]
00441C22 8B18             mov ebx,[eax]
00441C24 FF530C           call dword ptr [ebx+$0c]
00441C27 8B55E0           mov edx,[ebp-$20]
00441C2A 8D45F0           lea eax,[ebp-$10]
00441C2D B9A81C4400       mov ecx,$00441ca8
00441C32 E8A573FCFF       call @IntfCast
```

You can see how the result of the FListeners[i] call is placed in [ebp-$20] and then `procedure _IntfCast(var Dest: IInterface; const Source: IInterface; const IID: TGUID);` is called on that (eax being the target, [ebp-$10], edx the source, [ebp-$20], and ecx the address where the appropriate guid can be found.

You can fix your code by changing the Broadcast method to:

```
procedure TBroadcaster.Broadcast(Msg: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
  Intf: IInterface;
  Listener: IListener;
begin
  for i := 0 to FListeners.Count-1 do begin
    Intf := FListeners[i];
    if Supports(Intf, IListener, Listener) then
      Listener.HandleMessage(Msg);
  end;
  Listener := nil;
  Intf := nil;

  FListeners.Clear;
  FreeAndNil(FListener);
end;//method epilogue: why is there a call to IntfClear and then TComponent._Release?
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need to spend more time learning how to read disassembled code.